# Fatal error installing Twiggy with Codeigniter/HMVC

Tags: php, codeigniter

when trying to install twiggy with codeigniter/HMVC I get the following error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   
> Severity: Notice
>   
> Message: Undefined property: CI::$twiggy
>   
> Filename: MX/Controller.php
>   
> Line Number: 58

I have installed twiggy as described on http://edmundask.github.io/codeigniter-twiggy/
The only thing I did was change the name of the spark `MY_Loader.php` to `MY_Spark_Loader.php` because it had the same name as the `HMVC MY_Loader.php`

I have autoloaded twiggy in the autoload.php like this:

```
$autoload['sparks'] = array('twiggy/0.8.5');
```

My controller looks like this:

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Test extends MX_Controller
{
   public function index()
   {
      $this->twiggy->display();
   }
}
```

Any help to get this running would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the autoloader is pointing to the correct location. Mine looks like this: `$autoload['sparks'] = array('../tools/sparks/Twiggy/0.8.5');`

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow this instruction

http://getsparks.org/set-up-mx

It explains how to install spark manager with hmvc, but there is a bug, if you run $this->router->fetch_modules() in modules which is run from another module it doesn't return current running module, it returns original module.

To fix that, don't replace MX/Loader.php with the one provided there, just use hmvc original file, but add two functions to load sparks from that loader to hmvc loader file.
For MX/Modules.php do the same thing, just take spark specific code to hmvc original file.

Sorry for my bad english. Hope you understand